# How do I center align icons on a web page in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to align the three icons with some spacing between them. My Code i.e. `landing.js` -

```
import React from 'react';
import MaterialIcon, {colorPalette} from 'material-icons-react';
 const Landing = () => (
    <div style={{background: "LightBlue"}}>
        <MaterialIcon icon="call" size='200' color={colorPalette.blue._200} />
        <MaterialIcon icon="search" size='200' vertical-align='50000px'/>
        <MaterialIcon icon="chat" size='200' vertical-align='right'/>
    </div>
);

export default Landing;
```

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Qrw2.png)

This code is just for the body component the header is in another file `header.js`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) layout should give you what you want:

```
 <div style={{
  background: "LightBlue",
  display: "flex", 
  justifyContent:"space-between",
  alignItems: "center"
  }}
>
     <MaterialIcon icon="call" size='200' color={colorPalette.blue._200} />
     <MaterialIcon icon="search" size='200' vertical-align='50000px'/>
     <MaterialIcon icon="chat" size='200' vertical-align='right'/>
 </div>
```

Comment: @Gaël-S  It is working but now I'm not able to get any space between the top navbar and the icons. Link - https://ibb.co/ZX2tVgg

Comment: you can add a `marginTop` property to the `div` containing the Icons or a `marginBottom` to the top navbar

Answer (score 1):

Are you searching for this?

```css
.icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon + .icon {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class='icon'></div>
  <div class='icon'></div>
  <div class='icon'></div>
</div>
```